# Can I use @vercel/og without React?

Tags: vercel

I'm trying to create an API on Vercel which returns images, generated based on the request. I would like to use [@vercel/og](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vercel/og) for this, because it can generate images from HTML, and it is very quick. However, it seems to require React, which seems entirely unnecessary for something serving no actual HTML at all.

I have an edge function in `api/test.ts`:

```
import { ImageResponse } from '@vercel/og';

export const config = {
    runtime: 'experimental-edge',
};

export default function () {
    return new ImageResponse({
        type: "div",
        props: {
            children: "Hello, World",
            style: {
                backgroundColor: "black",
                color: "white",
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
            }
        }
    }, { width: 500, height: 500 });
}
```

This runs completely fine when deployed to Vercel, but when I use `vercel dev` it gives me these errors:

```
Failed to instantiate edge runtime.
Invalid URL: ../vendor/noto-sans-v27-latin-regular.ttf
Error: Failed to complete request to /api/test: Error: socket hang up
node_modules/@vercel/og/dist/og.d.ts:1:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import type { ReactElement } from 'react';
                                    ~~~~~~~

node_modules/satori/dist/index.d.ts:1:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { ReactNode } from 'react';
                            ~~~~~~~

node_modules/satori/dist/index.d.ts:14:11 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node`.

14     data: Buffer | ArrayBuffer;
             ~~~~~~


Found 3 errors.
```

There are two errors saying that @vercel/og and [satori](https://www.npmjs.com/package/satori) can't find React. Is there a way around this? I shouldn't need react for this, right?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the React-related errors and the inability to run .tsx edge functions without Next.js by installing `@types/react` and defining my own JSX function and using it without JSX syntax just in a `.ts` file.

```
function h<T extends React.ElementType<any>>(
  type: T,
  props: React.ComponentPropsWithRef<T>,
  ...children: React.ReactNode[]
) {
  return {
    type,
    key: "key" in props ? props.key : null,
    props: {
      ...props,
      children: children && children.length ? children : props.children,
    },
  };
}
```

After this you can run it in Vercel deployment preview.

However, in `vercel dev` locally, I'm still getting the following error.

```
Failed to instantiate edge runtime.
Invalid URL: ../vendor/noto-sans-v27-latin-regular.ttf
Error: Failed to complete request to /api/og: Error: socket hang up
```

I had also forced `vercel` CLI to use the newer TypeScript version with `pnpm.overrides` in package.json to solve some TypeScript parse errors I was getting.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use it without React, but as [@hasparus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74960034/1843592) pointed out you won't be able to use JSX function.

I spent some time getting it to work, and encountered some of the same struggles getting it to work locally. Edge Functions simply don't seem to operate all that well with `vercel dev`.

I discovered an undocumented `unstable_createNodejsStream` function in the package, which I was able to get working both locally, and live on Vercel. I wrote about it [on my website here](https://jwie.be/blog/using-vercel-og-without-nextjs), but here's the gist:

1. `import { unstable_createNodejsStream } from '@vercel/og'`
2. Update your handler to a default Node.js handler, i.e., `export default async function (req, res) {}`
3. Write your HTML as a standard JS object in the expected JSX output format, use the custom `h()` function defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74960034/1843592) by hasparus, or `import { h } from 'preact'` and write it in JSX format
4. Create a new stream using `unstable_createNodejsStream` and pipe it to the response

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple example for generating open graph images with no react, no framework at all. Just one dependency:

https://www.jakubpelak.com/posts/vercel-og-card-no-framework

Sadly, as @hasparus mentioned, it currently does not run locally. However, I am currently getting a different error. I remember getting the same one before (font related). Then, a few months back, it has gotten fixed and code ran smoothly even on local machine. Not at this moment, thougn. Hopefully it gets fixed soon.